# Ошибка "Индекс находился вне границ массива" C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Пишу простую программу WindowsForm, никак не пойму как исправить эту ошибку

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = @"C:\STUDENT\student.txt";
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filename);
            string[] values; //
            string newline; // считанная строка из файла

            string ln;
            string fn;
            string gr;
            double ex;
            double cw;
            Student s;
            student_list = new List<Student>();
            // считываем до конца файла
            while ((newline = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                values = newline.Split(' '); // строку разбиваем на части(lastname,firstname и т.д.), используя разделить пробел Split(' ')
                ln = values[0]; // присваиваем ячейкам строки
                fn = values[1]; // присваиваем ячейкам строки // Вот тут выдаёт ошибку
                gr = values[2]; // присваиваем ячейкам строки
                ex = Convert.ToDouble(values[3]);
                cw = Convert.ToDouble(values[4]);
                s = new Student(ln, fn, gr, ex, cw);
                student_list.Add(s);

            }
            file.Close();
```

Comment: Скорей всего в файле попадается пустая строка и соответственно массив `values` не будет содержать более одного элемента.  Перед обращением к строкам в массиве `values`  добавьте проверку количества элементов.